# preserve-order set true does not run TestNG tests in order with group dependencies defined

Tags: webdriver, testng

I am trying to run grouped TestNG tests. The given xml is a test in testng.xml:

```
<test name="demo test" preserve-order="true">
       <groups>
         <run>
           <include name="openlogin"/>
           <include name="login"/>
           <include name="searchPatient"/>
           <include name="scheduleBySearch" />
           <include name="openDashboardFromPatientToday"/>
           <include name="openPatientChart"/>
           <include name="referralSearch"/>
           <include name="referralNotes"/>
           <include name="removeReferral"/>
           <include name="nonExistingReferralSearch"/>
         </run>

         <dependencies>
            <group name="removeReferral" depends-on="referralNotes"/>
            <group name="referralNotes" depends-on="referralSearch"/>
            <group name="referralSearch" depends-on="openPatientChart"/>
            <group name="openPatientChart" depends-on="openDashboardFromPatientToday"/>
            <group name="openDashboardFromPatientToday" depends-on="scheduleBySearch"/>
            <group name="scheduleBySearch" depends-on="searchPatient" />
            <group name="searchPatient" depends-on="login" />
            <group name="login" depends-on="openlogin"/>
         </dependencies>
        </groups>

        <classes>
         <class name="xtr.webaut.sanitytests.LoginTests"/>
         <class name="xtr.webaut.sanitytests.PatientSearchTest"/>
         <class name="xtr.webaut.sanitytests.PatientScheduleTests"/>
         <class name="xtr.webaut.sanitytests.PatientTodayTests"/>
         <class name="xtr.webaut.sanitytests.PatientDashboardViewTests"/>
         <class name="xtr.webaut.sanitytests.PatientChartReferralTests"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
```

Here there is a group "nonExistingReferralSearch" that I don't want to be dependent upon any other group. But I want it to be executed in the specified order and I have set "preserve-order" as true for the `<test>`. While execution, I find that TestNG does not execute the non-dependent group in order. It executes that group immediately after the group "openlogin" whereas I am expecting it to get executed in the end. 

Is it wrong to define dependencies as well as tell TestNG to maintain an order of execution? Is there an unknown priority defined that TestNG will execute any non-dependent tests/groups first and then the dependent tests? I hope it is not that inflexible.
 

Even for a generic scenario in a `<test>`, is it not possible to run some test methods/groups without any dependency and some test methods/groups with dependencies, **in an order**?

Comment: Ever found the answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

I added the preserve-order parameter in the suite. The tests run in the order we specified.

```
<suite name="Suite" preserve-order="true">
```

Comment: I have preserve-order set "true" in my suite as well. Doesn't work.

Comment: check whether you have parallel = "methods"

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me when I gave like this .

```
<test name="Suite" preserve-order="true"  parallel="false" enabled="true">
```