# Qmetry: Order of test cases execution not happening as per the given order in testNG file

Tags: testng, qaf

In Qmetry - Order of test cases execution not happening as per the given order in testNG file.

**Order of test cases in testng xml file** (with preserve-order="true"):

```
<test name="611e18500e79671e660bde2c - Config-1" enabled="true" preserve-order="true">
            <parameter name="env.resources" value="resources;EXECUTIONS/exec_1"/>
            <groups>
                <run>
                    <include name="@611e18500e79671e660bde2f" />   //test1
                    <include name="@611e18500e79671e660bde30" />   //test2
                    <include name="@611e18500e79671e660bde31" />   //test3
```

**After execution - Order of execution**:

```
611e18500e79671e660bde31   //test3
611e18500e79671e660bde2f   //test1
611e18500e79671e660bde30   //test2
```

Can any one help me on how to maintain the test cases execution order as per given order in testng xml file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052633/preserve-order-set-true-does-not-run-testng-tests-in-order-with-group-dependenci

Comment: Can any one please help us with solution for above issue? . Not able to understand where the issue is.